# New entity not comiting to database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, repository-pattern

I am using the repository pattern with entity framework 5. When I add a new user to my users entity, it does not get saved to the database. Any ideas why??

I have the following structure -

> DAL (contains Entity Framework model) -> Core -> Web

Form1.cs

```
UserService _userService = new UserService();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.DataSource = _userService.GetUserList(10, 1).Users;
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "FullName";
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserModel newUser = new UserModel();
        newUser.Username = tbUsername.Text;
        newUser.FirstName = tbFirstname.Text;
        newUser.Surname = tbLastname.Text;
        newUser.Password = tbPassword.Text;
        newUser.LoginEnabled = true;
        newUser.UserStatus = UserStatus.Active;

        _userService.Add(newUser);
    }
```

UserService.cs

```
public void Add(UserModel entity)
    {
        User newUser = new User();
        newUser.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;

        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<UserModel, User>();

        try
        {
            _userRepository.Add(AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(entity, newUser));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

RepositoryBase.cs

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepository<T>
    where T : class
{
    public RepositoryBase()
        : this(new AcRepositoryContext())
    {
    }

    public RepositoryBase(IRepositoryContext repositoryContext)
    {
        repositoryContext = repositoryContext ?? new AcRepositoryContext();
        _objectSet = repositoryContext.GetObjectSet<T>();
    }

    private IObjectSet<T> _objectSet;
    public IObjectSet<T> ObjectSet
    {
        get
        {
            return _objectSet;
        }
    }

    #region IRepository Members

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        this.ObjectSet.AddObject(entity);
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        this.ObjectSet.DeleteObject(entity);
    }

    public IList<T> GetAll()
    {
        return this.ObjectSet.ToList<T>();
    }

    public IList<T> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereCondition)
    {
        return this.ObjectSet.Where(whereCondition).ToList<T>();
    }

    public T GetSingle(Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereCondition)
    {
        return this.ObjectSet.Where(whereCondition).FirstOrDefault<T>();
    }

    public void Attach(T entity)
    {
        this.ObjectSet.Attach(entity);
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetQueryable()
    {
        return this.ObjectSet.AsQueryable<T>();
    }

    public long Count()
    {
        return this.ObjectSet.LongCount<T>();
    }

    public long Count(Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereCondition)
    {
        return this.ObjectSet.Where(whereCondition).LongCount<T>();
    }

    #endregion

}
```

AcRepositoryContext.cs

```
public class AcRepositoryContext : IRepositoryContext
{
    private const string OBJECT_CONTEXT_KEY = "AC.DAL.AccessControlDBEntities";
    public IObjectSet<T> GetObjectSet<T>()
        where T : class
    {
        try
        {
            return ContextManager.GetObjectContext(OBJECT_CONTEXT_KEY).CreateObjectSet<T>();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the active object context
    /// </summary>
    public ObjectContext ObjectContext
    {
        get
        {
            return ContextManager.GetObjectContext(OBJECT_CONTEXT_KEY);
        }
    }

    public int SaveChanges()
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Terminate()
    {
        ContextManager.SetRepositoryContext(null, OBJECT_CONTEXT_KEY);
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Door> Doors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Repository implementation class (`RepositoryBase` or its children), you should have a call to the context's `SaveChanges`.

For instance, in `RepositoryBase<T>`, I would add this method:

```
public void Commit()
{
   repositoryContext.SaveChanges()
}
```

After you perform your call to `Add()` in your `btnAdd_Click` event handler, you should call this `Commit` method to save changes to the database.

For more information, take a look at this blog:

[Using the Repository Pattern in Entity Framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2013/08/23/using-repository-pattern-in-entity-framework.aspx)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have added to the post the AcRepositoryContext.cs file. I cannot seem to access any SaveChanges() method from the RepositoryBase<T>?

Comment: Well, the save needs to happen through your Repository Context class which is available only in your RepositoryBase class from what I can see. Hence my suggestion. However, you know your object hierarchy and inheritance better, so please use your better judgment to place it in an appropriate place. :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see in your repository where you call SaveChanges on your AcRepositoryContext I'm assuming this inherits from dbcontext or more likely from your naming convention objectcontext

So after you've added a new entity or updated or deleted then you need to save changes to have those changes persisted to the database.

I can see in your userservice class where you add an entity to the repository but you don't appear to call SaveChanges on the context afterwards.